# PHP Include does not reflect file changes

Tags: php, include

I have a personal web site at a PHP host and include a fixed header file (a simple HTML banner and menu etc.) in every page. I include header with PHP include command; however although I change the header file the change does not reflect to the files which include it.

When I open the header file manually with browser I see changes; also when I delete the file other files cannot show the menu etc (so I am dealing with the correct file) but the changes do not show on includers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try emptying your browser's cache.

Comment: PHP should normally detect this. Does the last changed time on the file change after your alteration? Is `APC` active?

Comment: Is this page in a CMS like Wordpress? If so, is a caching plugin turned on? Or is there caching on the server side (APC as Wrikken mentions, or file cache)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would talk to the host.  They may be caching the header file as a "service" for you.  If so, it may show up in a day or so.

-Dave